# C - Enforcing string parameter to be in read-only memory

Tags: c, gcc

I'm optimizing some code, and I have a function like this:

```
const char * gStrPtr = NULL;

void foo (const char *str) {
     gStrPtr = strdup(str);
}
```

As of now, `foo()` is only called with constant strings.  eg:

```
const char fooStr[]="Some really long string...";
foo(fooStr);
```

Notice that because it's always called with a constant, I should be able to just do:

```
void foo (const char *str) {
     gStrPtr=str;
}
```

But, it opens up a sharp stick: if someone in the future breaks the convention, and tries calling `foo()` with a dynamic copy of a string that is later freed, it could cause undefined behavior.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a compile-time or even a run-time check that checks if `str` is in read-only memory to avoid expensive bug-chases down the road.

Note: if I assume str is a string literal, then I can do it with a macro as so:

```
#define foo(str)  foo_func("" str)
```

which will cause compile errors on non string-literals.   But it also does not accept pointers to const chars.

---

**EDIT**

I thought I would post this after the discussion below.   @CraigEtsy pointed out the use of `__builtin_constant_p`, which is a best-effort approach at this problem (but will likely suffice for my needs).   I did the following tests with this, and got these results:

```
void foo(const char *str) {
        if (__builtin_constant_p(*str))
                printf("%s is constant\n", str);
        else
                printf("%s is not constant\n", str);
}

const char globalArray[] = "globalArray";
const char *globalPtr = "globalPtr";

int main()
{
    const char localArray[]="localArray";
    const char *localPtr="localPtr";
    char localNonConst[]="localNonConst";
    foo("literal");     // constant
    foo(localArray);    // not constant
    foo(localPtr);      // constant
    foo(globalArray);   // constant
    foo(globalPtr);     // not constant
    foo(localNonConst); // not constant
}
```

And when compiled with -O3, it gave results:

```
literal is constant
localArray is not constant
localPtr is constant
globalArray is constant
globalPtr is not constant
localNonConst is not constant
```

So, for my particular case, I can just switch the `const char arr[]="str"`'s to `const char * arr="str"`, and then, in my `foo()`, I can check if the value is constant, and allocate memory and raise a runtime warning if not (and mark a flag so I know whether to free the pointer later on...).

Comment: The issue is not read-only memory but static storage (e.g. I can dynamically allocate read-only memory with `mmap` and release it later). I don't think you can check for that.

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: I supposed I'd be wanting to check if the pointer lies in the `.text` section...

Comment: What if you `void myfunc() { const char mystr[] = "abc"; foo(mystr); }` and then later use gStrPtr? Is `mystr` in read-only memory? What is a read-only memory?

Comment: The memory for variable `fooStr` may be placed in not-'read-only' memory, but the initialization routine of your executable may initialize the memory with the desired content. What then? Then `fooStr` will not be in `read-only` memory and you can modify it (on this architecture, it's implementation dependent, you shouldn't do that and it's undefined behaviour.).

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Not `.rodata`?

Comment: @melpomene -- yes, in `.text` or in `.rodata` (or any other user-defined section which is read-only for that matter...)

Comment: Any method to check whether a string is in a read only marked page (using the OS API) is going to be costlier that `strdup`. So defeats the purpose of your "optimization".

Comment: @KamilCuk -- in your example the "abc" would likely be put in `.text` or `.rodata`, and thus be _immutable_  (Thanks @R...) ... however  I just realized, it could also be in a `.init` section, which could be freed before gStrPtr is used....   sigh...

Comment: It will. Inside an ELF file format on x86 or x86_64 architecture using gcc compiler. On Cortex-M0+ processor with Keli compiler with hex output the thing is different. There is no portable way of doing that, so specify on which architectures, which compilers are you interested in.

Comment: You may be able to use [with `gcc`], the `__builtin_constant_p` function and a macro that does `strdup` if the function returns false. It returns true if you give it `"abc"` and false otherwise. You could then range check against the `.rodata` section and set directly if within, but do `strdup` if not. Perhaps too much messiness but I thought I'd pass it along.

Comment: `__builtin_constant_p("abc")` returns true, but `void *p = "abc"; __builtin_constant_p(p);` returns false without optimization and true with optimizations (gcc8.2.0). I guess the section-check way is the only way.

Comment: @KamilCuk -- I was just looking into it.  I'm not clear wherether it is testing that p is constant, or whether what it points to is constant...    I'll try some experiments.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html for info on `__builtin_constant_p`.  It will evaluate true if the expression is known to be a compile-time constant. Knowledge of this requires optimization in most cases. I believe you should use `*p`, not `p`, since you want to know if the string constants are constant, not the address of the string.

Comment: The C standard has no concept of read-only memory, only of objects. `const` does not mean "constant", but is a guarantte given by the programmer. If  you want to shoot your foot, C happily holds the gun for you.

Comment: I'll put an edit to my post, as I don't have enough space in the comment, but basically on my system `const char *ptr = "X"` will result in `*ptr` being a constant, but `const char ptr[] = "X"`, will NOT result in `*ptr` being considered a constant. I think though, for my particular case, I can use this method (I always compile with optimization, etc). @CraigEstey -- if you can post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any reasonable way to enforce this at runtime, at least not without machinery that would be many orders of magnitude more expensive than just calling `strdup`.

If the function is only supposed to take *immutable* strings as arguments (that's the word you're looking for -- immutable, in the sense that its lifetime will be the remainder of the process's lifetime and its contents will not change for the remainder of its lifetime), this needs to be a documented part of its interface contract.

Comment: Thanks.  I was coming to the same  conclusion, but thought I'd ask in case anyone had any clever tricks I overlooked.   Unfortunately I don't trust future coders to read the comments.    I may force everyone to use literals instead of const char arrays, and then use the macro trick...

Comment: You can define your function as a macro and have the macro stringify its argument before passing it to the function Then there's no way to pass a non-string-literal without bypassing the macro. ;-)

Comment: Depending on platform, checking if the pointer is within the read-only data section is a lot cheapr than dynamic allocation

Comment: @M.M: Perhaps, but that's a big if, and has a lot of caveats unless you're in a simple static-linked case. With dynamic linking and loading you'd need the function to probe for new shared libraries each time it's called, and that's going to be a lot more expensive than allocation. Also, does read-only memory in shared libraries count as immutable (which is what OP really needs) if the library was loaded at runtime and might be subject to unloading via `dlclose`? I would say no, but the point here is that the definition isn't even clear.